# How can I import data from MongoDB to Panda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pandas

I want to analyze a database hosted in Mongo. Therefore, I want to connect the mongo URI to pandas, so I can run all my python queries freely in my Jupyter Lab environment.

Let's day that this is my mongo connection:

"mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://test:test12345@cluster0-ze0tw.mongodb.net/databasetest?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

I have read other answer, and they shared this code that supposedly might help me out with this connection. I am not quite if I am filling out the fields correctly. Can you guys walk me through using as an example the connection shown above.

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient


def _connect_mongo(host, port, username, password, db):
   """ A util for making a connection to mongo """

   if username and password:
       mongo_uri = 'mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s' % (username, password, host, port, db)
       conn = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
   else:
       conn = MongoClient(host, port)


   return conn[db]


def read_mongo(db, collection, query={}, host='localhost', port=27017, 
username=None, password=None, no_id=True):
   """ Read from Mongo and Store into DataFrame """

   # Connect to MongoDB
   db = _connect_mongo(host=host, port=port, username=username, password=password, 
   db=db)

   # Make a query to the specific DB and Collection
   cursor = db[collection].find(query)

   # Expand the cursor and construct the DataFrame
   df =  pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))

   # Delete the _id
   if no_id:
       del df['_id']

   return df
```

Comment: Please post how you ran that piece of code and its result.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are connecting to the MongoDB Atlas instance. First of all check if your Python client machine's IP is in the [Atlas IP Whitelist](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/) (Security->Network Access->IP Whitelist).

Comment: At the moment is open: 0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)